# Wix Burn Bundle: Show ExePackages Output

Tags: cmd, wix, burn

Hello together I have a script with some commands adjusting some things on the system that I am using within the Chain of a Burn Bundle like this:

```
<ExePackage Id="ABC" DetectCondition="no" Permanent="no" SourceFile="scripts\adjustStuff.cmd" Vital="no" After="XYZ" />
```

However when the Bundle executes the script there is no terminal open.

But I actually need the user to interact with the terminal. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although its not working directly through WiX. You could adjust your batch script and executing the commands via the start command which starts a new terminal.

For example:

```
start /max cmd /k "command1 /para1 /para2 & command2 ...."
```

Answer (score 1):

No. That is not supported today.